# Can any function $f\geq 0$ when integrated give a discontinuous function?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to find a real-valued function $f\geq 0$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f$ gives a discontinuous function?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable (or just Lebesgue integrable on $(-\infty,x)$ for every $x$) then no. If $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable then it's not clear what the question means...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'm assuming f could be Lebesgue integrable, and maybe not Riemann Integrable.  I should have said that the integration is done using the Riemann Integral. I'm still learning this, so I'm sorry if I'm  incorrect or imprecise...

Comment: Now you're making no sense that I can see, sorry. You say you're assuming $f$ is Lebesgue integrable but the integral is the Riemann integral???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich for example, isn't the indicator function for the set of rationals Lebesgue integrable, but the Rieman integral for that function doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes. I don't see what that has to do with my question. Read it again. Anyway, I have to go to work: The answer is yes if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable _and_ you're asking about the Lebesgue integral. Hint: this follows from the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Could you give an example of a function to which the answer is yes? Thanks

Comment: I'm not getting this at all. For the third time, the answer is yes for any Lebesgue integrable function!

Comment: @David: you have to admit that it is confusing when you went to say that the answer is no in your first comment, to say a couple times that the answer is yes ;)

Comment: @MartinArgerami Oops. Yes, it's confusing. The problem was I forgot the exact phrasing of the question - in my first comments "no" meant "no, can't be discontinuous", while later I had a sign flipped - when I said yes I meant yes,  must be continuous, which should have been "no", not "yes"...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Sorry, I've been confused about "no" versus "yes'. Anyway: If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable then $F$ is continuous. I don't know an example where $F$ is not continuous. The function would have to be integrable in some sense for $F$ to _exist_, and I don't know a sense of integrability that allows $F$ to exist and be discontinuous.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich ok. thanks for you help. ;)